# Creating 2 arrays of 2 structs.

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

I have been given a problem domain. To write a program which asks the user which fruits he wants to purchase and in how much quantity. Based on the input from the user, it produces a bill.
Example interaction: 
Do you want to purchase fruit? Yes

Which fruit? Orange

How many pounds ? 2

Do you want to purchase another fruit? Yes

Which fruit? Apple

How many pounds? 1.5

Do you want to purchase anothe fruit? No

Thanks for your business.

Here is your bill:

Fruit                       Quantity                 Price per Lb              Price

Orange                     2 Lb                         1.5                                    3

Apple                        1.5 Lb                     2                                         3

Total Amount                                                                                      6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct fruitData
{
    string fruitName;
    float price;
};

struct invoiceData
{
    char fruit_ordered;
    float price1;
    float quantity_ordered;
    float totalFruitprice;
} ;


int main()

    char choice;
    string fruit_choice;
    float pounds_choice;
    int count=0;

    fruitData fruits[5];
    invoiceData customers[5];

    strcpy(fruits[0].fruitName, "Banana");
    strcpy(fruits[1].fruitName, "Apple");
    strcpy(fruits[2].fruitName, "Pears");
    strcpy(fruits[3].fruitName, "Oranges");
    strcpy(fruits[4].fruitName, "Papaya");

    fruits[0].price=1;
    fruits[1].price=2;
    fruits[2].price=2.5;
    fruits[3].price=1.5;
    fruits[5].price=1.40;

    strcpy(customers[0].fruitName, "Banana");
    strcpy(customers[1].fruitName, "Apple");
    strcpy(customers[2].fruitName, "Pears");
    strcpy(customers[3].fruitName, "Oranges");
    strcpy(customers[4].fruitName, "Papaya");

    customers[0].price=1;
    customers[1].price=2;
    customers[2].price=2.5;
    customers[3].price=1.5;
    customers[4].price=1.40;


    cout << "Welcome to the fruit market" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to purchase fruit?" << endl;
    cin >> choice >> endl;

    while (choice == 'Y')
    {
    cout << "Which fruit?" << endl;
    cin >> fruit_choice >> endl;

    cout << "How many pounds?" << endl;
    cin >> pounds_choice >> endl;

    if (fruit_choice == "Banana")
    {
    customers[0].quantity_ordered = pounds_choice;
    customers[0].total_price = customers[0].quantity_ordered * customers[0].price;
    }
    else if (fruit_choice == "Apple")
    {
    customers[1].quantity_ordered = pounds_choice;
    customers[1].total_price = customers[1].quantity_ordered * customers[1].price;
    }
    else if (fruit_choice == "Pears")
    {
    customers[2].quantity_ordered = pounds_choice;
    customers[2].total_price = customers[2].quantity_ordered * customers[2].price;
    }
    else if (fruit_choice == "Oranges")
    {
    customers[3].quantity_ordered = pounds_choice;
    customers[3].total_price = customers[3].quantity_ordered * customers[3].price;
    }
    else (fruit_choice == "Papaya")
    {
    customers[4].quantity_ordered = pounds_choice;
    customers[4].total_price = customers[4].quantity_ordered * customers[4].price;
    }
    }

    for (count = 1 ; count <=5 ; count++)
    {
    if (customers[0].total_price != 0)
    {
        cout << customers[0].fruit_name <<
        cout << customers[0].quantity_ordered <<
        cout << customers[0].price <<
        cout << customers[0].total_price <<

    }
    }



}
```

I am getting a lot of errors. One of them being the string in "string fruit_chioce" is not turning blue as it should. And the compiler says char choice should be preceded by a ";" . I am also having trouble associating an array for these structs. Any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Comment: No opening { for main() for starters.

Comment: fruits[5] as in fruits[5].price is out of bounds.

Comment: You can't (easily) mix C++ strings and 'C' strings. Stick to C++. Try `fruits[0].fruitName = "Banana"` etc. Or better, initialize an array as `fruitData fruits[] = { "Banana", "Apple", ... };`

Comment: Suggest: re-examine all your code. There's lots of issues not just what you asked about. It is unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

In the strcuture fruitData

```
struct fruitData
{
    string fruitName;
    float price;
};
```

data member fruitName is defined as having type `std::string`.  You may not use standard C function `strcpy` with objects of type `std::string` because they are not character arrays. You could use a simple assignment. For example

```
fruits[0].fruitName = "Banana";
```

But it would be better to initialize the array when it was defined. For example

```
fruitData fruits[5] = 
{
    { "Banana", 1 }, { "Apple", 2 }, { "Pears", 2.5 }, 
    { "Oranges", 1.5 }, { "Papaya", 1.40 }
};
```

Also in structure invoiceData you defined data member fruit_ordered as

```
char fruit_ordered;
```

(a very strange decision) that is it can contain only one character. Moreover I think you meant fruitName instead of fruit_ordered because below you wrote

```
strcpy(customers[0].fruitName, "Banana");
```

but the structure does not declare this name. So again you may not use standard C function `strcpy`  as you did because fruitName is not a character array.

Moreover you did not include header `<cstring>` where C functions are declared.

This statement (and similar statements)

```
cin >> choice >> endl;
```

is invalid. You may not use `std::endl` with `std::cin`

Also this loop

```
for (count = 1 ; count <=5 ; count++)
{
if (customers[0].total_price != 0)
{
    cout << customers[0].fruit_name <<
    cout << customers[0].quantity_ordered <<
    cout << customers[0].price <<
    cout << customers[0].total_price <<

}
}
```

has no any sense.

I think there are other errors but it is enogh what i already showed.  Take into account that valid range of indexes for an array having 5 elements is 0 - 4

In this code

```
fruits[0].price=1;
fruits[1].price=2;
fruits[2].price=2.5;
fruits[3].price=1.5;
fruits[5].price=1.40;
```

you have a typo. Here the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 but must be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Shortly speaking the code is full of errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. After `int main()` there should be a `{` immediately following.
2. `fruits` is only 5 elements long, but you try to access the sixth here: (I guess it really should be `4` instead of `5`)

   ```
   fruits[5].price=1.40;
   ```
3. `fruitName` is a C++ string, you can't use `strcpy` with it (`strcpy` is for C strings, that is `char*`-based strings). Simply assign:

   ```
   fruits[0].fruitName = "Banana";
   ```
4. Your `while` loop will never end, because you never ask again for input to `choice`.
5. Your last `else` here

   ```
   else (fruit_choice == "Papaya")
   ```

   should also be a `else if`.
6. Your for loop goes from zero to five (sixth element), but the array only has 5 elements, so it should be:

   ```
   for (count = 1 ; count < 5 ; count++)
   ```
7. The last output lines should end with an operand (some variable to output) instead of `<<`. Also like every other statement they have to end with `;`. For example with line break:

   ```
   cout << customers[count].fruit_name << endl;
   ```

   I also replaced `0` with `count`, because you surely don't want to always output the first array element.

Comment: See other answers for some stuff that I missed.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help . I have successfully submitted this Lab.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use std::vector. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Fruit {
    string name;
    float price;
};

int main() {
    vector<Fruit> fruits;

    while(true) {
        Fruit fruit;
        string answer;
        cout << "Which fruit? ";
        cin >> fruit.name;
        cout << "How many pounds? ";
        cin >> fruit.price;
        fruits.push_back(fruit);
        cout << "Do you want to purchase another fruit? ";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;
        if (answer=="No") break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<(int)fruits.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Fruit " << i+1 << " -> Name: " << fruits[i].name << ", price: " << fruits[i].price << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```